# HDMI port working with select devices after accident

Tags: hdmi, vga, external-display

I have an ASUS GL752VW ROG laptop.
I use a VGA monitor with my HDMI port through an HDMI to VGA converter.

The laptop is exhibiting extremely strange HDMI behavior after it fell by accident yesterday. I had to replace the converter because the port got broken. Now whenever I connect a monitor the laptop would recognize it but there is absolutely no output or signal detected by the monitor.

I know the new HDMI to VGA converter is working (tried two converters, and two different VGA monitors, and two VGA-VGA cables.)

Before you think the HDMI port itself got broken when the laptop fell.. It works perfectly with my HDMI to composite video converter, without any external power.

So to sum it up, everything was working well until the laptop fell. Now the HDMI output only works when I connect it to the HDMI to composite video converter, but not the HDMI to VGA converters, even though it would recognize the monitor when connected.

I can't even theorize what is going on. There's a more expensive brand of converter that has an external power jack. I'm not sure if this would help. Any clue would be extremely helpful.

Comment: This would be really hard to troubleshoot over the internet.  However, it sounds like something on the motherboard has been broken.

Comment: It does sound like the HDMI port on the laptop got damaged, no matter if it works with some devices and not with other devices. Depending on what pins might have been damaged, some devices can still receive the signal. Since HDMI data and clock signals are differential pairs, it is possible that one wire of a differential pair is broken, and some devices can still receive this and some don't.